# Safari calls event handler after detaching element from the DOM

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

I have some element which has two listeners: `click` and `mouseLeave`. On click, I need to remove it from the DOM. Everything looks not so difficult but I've noticed that in Safari after detaching the element `mouseleave` event handler triggers. In other browsers, it works correctly. I'd like to know why does it happen and then how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```js
const blockNode = document.querySelector('.block');

blockNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  blockNode.parentNode.removeChild(blockNode);
});

blockNode.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  console.log('mouse leave!');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Side note: Never use `alert` to look at what happens with DOM events. It mucks things up.

Comment: Your Stack Snippet doesn't trigger the alert on iOS Safari. Does this only happen on Mac?

Comment: The obvious thing to try is to remove the event listener when removing the element, or set a flag telling your handler not to do anything. Have you tried either of those?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've tried to use removeEventListener. It works but only in the case when the event handler isn't an anonymous function.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the function is anonymous, all that matters is whether you have a reference to it. So keep a reference to it.